# Personal keylogger

Tags: windows, software-rec, logging

I know keyloggers are a quite grey area. Why do I need a keylogger?
vBulitan has an annoying feature. If you keep a session open for many hours and afterwards want to post in a thread without loading a new page the session times out.
I lost quite a few posts that way.
I want to install a keylogger on my computer to rescue those posts.

I'm also interested into the [Quantified Self](http://www.quantifiedself.com/) movement. As a result it would also be nice if the keylogger would keep timestamps.

Lastly it would be good if the keylogger writes to an encrypted file for data safety issues.
Can someone recommend a program to me?

At the moment I'm running Windows Vista but I'm thinking about upgrading to Windows 7.

Answer (score 4):

I won't answer your question, but I'll provide you a solution.

[Lazarus](http://lazarus.interclue.com/) was made to solve the exact same problem that you have right now. Runs in FFx or Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

PYkeylogger http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/pykeylogger/index.php?title=Main_Page

It has to be compiled or bought to get it to work for more than a few days, its not hard to compile.

If you really need it for VBulletin, you might want to look at Lazursus or other firefox and chrome extentions that serve the same purpose without putting spyware on your computer.