# Windows 7: Free Key Logger

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, anti-virus, keylogger

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Personal keylogger](https://superuser.com/questions/193860/personal-keylogger)

What free key logger software would you recommend for Windows 7? Something that runs in stealth mode and gets along with antivirus?

Intentions: I just want to keep it running on my machine, to keep log of my own activities.

Comment: I don't think you could have worded that any more suspiciously.

Comment: Suspiciously??? I just want to keep it running on my machine, to keep log of my own activities. I am sorry if I posted at the wrong place.

Comment: @RJ: I agree - it would be one thing for a higher-rep, respected user to ask this question, but with 1 rep and an unregistered user...

Comment: @t3ch:  edited answer to reflect intentions...

Comment: Keeping a log of your own activities with a key logger? I totally agree with RJFalconer, this really does sound fishy. Besides, any good antivir should be able to detect a keylogger. If you expect a honest tip, try to explain your intentions a little bit more.

Comment: I really dont understand why its looked suspicious. Its a case of stalking and I am following the advice of my officer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to track your personal time, programs used, activities, etc, check out **[ManicTime](http://manictime.com/)**.

- Auto tracking of computer usage
- Keep track of your work hours
- Simple and intuitive UI
- Local storage
- Powerful statistics

*Free and paid* versions, the free version works very well, highly recommend.

[image]

Comment: @t3ch: welcome! hope you have a better experience with Super User in the future. :)