# Visible Keylogger (ie not evil)

Tags: software-rec, logging

I want keylogging software on my laptop for lifelogging purposes.  But the software I can find is targeted towards stealth activity.  Can anyone recommend a keylogging software targeted towards personal backup.

**Ideal Functionality**

- Runs publicly (like in the task bar).
- Easy to turn off (via keyboard shortcut is best... at least via button click)
- Encrypted log
- Fast
- Free
- Cross platform ( windows at least )

The best I have found is [pykeylogger](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/pykeylogger/index.php?title=Main_Page) which does not attempt to be stealthy, but does not attempt to be visible either.  I want a keylogger focused on transparency, speed, and security so I can safely record myself.

*note: [Christian](https://superuser.com/users/2926/christian) has a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/193860/personal-keylogger) with a different emphasis

Comment: Sounds like a great software programming project for someone. You might state which OS it needs to work with.

Answer (score 5):

I hacked out a solution that will work OK for me.  I'm still interested in better answers.

Here is a autohotkey script that is simple enough that you can read it.  It runs publicly so you can turn it off.  No bells and whistles but maybe useful to some of you.

This solution meets some of the criteria

- Runs publically
- Easy to turn off via the task bar
- Fast
- Free

It does not meet other criteria

- not encrypted
- not tested for cross platform compatibility

It also adds requirements

- Need AutoHotKey
- Manual Installation

This will work for those of you familiar with AutoHotKey.  You will need to set your own keylog_path.  I will give full installation instructions if anyone needs them.  Here is the script:

```
; Visible KeyLog (not evil) 
; bmh Oct 2010 <benjamin.haley@gmail.com>
; free to all

; Configuration Variables
    keylog_path = *C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\keylog.txt
    #NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.

; Log All letters, numbers and some grammar symbols
; * avoids interrupting input
; ~ ignores case
                *~a::log("a", keylog_path)
                *~b::log("b", keylog_path)
                *~c::log("c", keylog_path)
                *~d::log("d", keylog_path)
                *~e::log("e", keylog_path)
                *~f::log("f", keylog_path)
                *~g::log("g", keylog_path)
                *~h::log("h", keylog_path)
                *~i::log("i", keylog_path)
                *~j::log("j", keylog_path)
                *~k::log("k", keylog_path)
                *~l::log("l", keylog_path)
                *~m::log("m", keylog_path)
                *~n::log("n", keylog_path)
                *~o::log("o", keylog_path)
                *~p::log("p", keylog_path)
                *~q::log("q", keylog_path)
                *~r::log("r", keylog_path)
                *~s::log("s", keylog_path)
                *~t::log("t", keylog_path)
                *~u::log("u", keylog_path)
                *~v::log("v", keylog_path)
                *~w::log("w", keylog_path)
                *~x::log("x", keylog_path)
                *~y::log("y", keylog_path)
                *~z::log("z", keylog_path)
                *~0::log("0", keylog_path)
                *~1::log("1", keylog_path)
                *~2::log("2", keylog_path)
                *~3::log("3", keylog_path)
                *~4::log("4", keylog_path)
                *~5::log("5", keylog_path)
                *~6::log("6", keylog_path)
                *~7::log("7", keylog_path)
                *~8::log("8", keylog_path)
                *~9::log("9", keylog_path)
                *~Space::log(" ", keylog_path)
                *~Enter::log("`n", keylog_path)
                *~.::log(".", keylog_path)
                *~,::log(",", keylog_path)    

;the logging function 
log( letter, path )
{
    fileappend, %letter%, %path%    
    return
}
```

Comment: +1 Ben, have you continued your development of this script?

Comment: I need installation instructions if you can provide them. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have come across a keylogging application that does nearly everything you want. It is called [Refog Keylogger](http://www.refog.com/keylogger.html) and has encrypted logs, is very fast, can run on Mac and Windows, has the option to be visible, can be paused easily, and has the option of running in the task bar/menu bar. Although it is not free, the demo version simply does not allow it to run in stealth mode (but you don't want that anyway), and does not allow you to send logs via email. (It may also show ads, but I am not sure about that.)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Refog touts itself as "Invisible and Undetectable" on its homepage.  It may be possible to run it visibly, but it smells of evil.

Comment: I can understand your trepidation. However, the application **defaults** to visible and detectable upon installation. While there are definitely other applications out there that may be "more visible," for your purposes I think that it would be the best.

(Additionally, if you are going for the life-logging angle, this application also takes screenshots.)